# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using simple codeigniter model function to update data and i am using REST_Controller. codeigniter database update give below error.

```
  <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
                <p>Error Number: 2014</p>
                <p>Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now</p>
                <p>UPDATE `user` SET `fname` = 'testuser', `lname` = 'test', `age` = '18', `email` = 'test@testmail.com', `education` = 'University', `marital_status` = 'married' 
    WHERE `user_id` = '2'</p>
                <p>Filename: controllers/api/Users.php</p>
                <p>Line Number: 218</p>
            </div>
```

below is my codeigniter function

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Users extends REST_Controller

{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     *  @return void
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');        
        $this->lang->load('message', 'english');
    }

    public function updateuser(){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $data = array('fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
                            'lname'=>$_POST['lname'],
                            'age'=>$_POST['age'],
                            'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                            'education'=>$_POST['education'],
                            'marital_status'=>$_POST['marital_status']
                            );

                    $this->User_model->update($data,$user_id);
    }
}
```

and second error when i am using MY_Model

```
  <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
                <p>Error Number: 2014</p>
                <p>Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now</p>
                <p>SHOW COLUMNS FROM `user_preferences`</p>
                <p>Filename: core/MY_Model.php</p>
                <p>Line Number: 206</p>
```

below is my User model Which is extend MY_Model user_id is primary key

```
<?php 
class User_model extends MY_Model
{
    public $primary_key = 'user_id';

    //callbacks
    public $before_create = array('timestamps');
    public $before_update = array('update_timestamp');
    public $before_get = array('getbefore');

     /**
     * Create timestamps before new user created
     * @param  array $user
     * @return array
     */
    protected function timestamps($user)
    {
        $user['created_date'] = $user['updated_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return $user;
    }



    /**
     * Update timestamp before update user details
     * @param  array $user
     * @return array
     */
    protected function update_timestamp($user)
    {
        $user['updated_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return $user;
    }

    /**
    * Check Before get Data
    * check conditions before get user data
    * 
    */
    protected function getbefore(){
        $this->db->where('is_deleted','0');
    }

}
?>
```

Does anyone has solution on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: You should give us the context of where you were running this.

Comment: ok i update pls wait a while.. Thanks for your time

Comment: please check now @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Foĺlow the link I pasted above.  You are doing something out of order.

Comment: All other controller function update work perfectly this one is causing error .....

Comment: Research the error, and it might be obvious what is wrong.

Comment: Please post model code also.

Comment: your mysql driver might be the problem 
refer  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324233/codeigniter-3-error-number-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-comman

Comment: paste you user_model code here

Comment: Please check updated question with my User_model @AmanMaurya

Answer (score -2):

change the method name update same as library method

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: What do you mean? update same as library means? And I forgot to told in question i am using REST_Controller for api.

Comment: yes i know but where i can change method name in user model or MY_Model ?

Comment: what do you mean ?